# Injecting javaScript into web page to disable a texbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

On my aspx page I have a asp button and when I click this button I want to disable this textbox using javascript by injecting it into the web page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#title').click(function () {
        $('#title').prop("disabled", true);
    });
});
```

I have this so far but instead of just applying this to my page I want to inject it into the web page

```
<div id="fieldone">
<asp:TextBox ID="title" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add html part as well so that we can suggest you a solution!

Comment: One more thing if you are working in ASP.net then you need to add use $('#<%=title.ClientID>').click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is in ASP context

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=yourbtn.ClientID%>').click(function () {
        $('#<%=title.ClientID%>').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
});
```

**Updated**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=yourbtn.ClientID%>','#<%=title.ClientID%>').click(function () {
            $('#<%=title.ClientID%>').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        });
    });
```

Comment: I want to be able to click on the textbox itself and when I do I want that textbox to disable

Answer (score 0):

Without your html I can only guess the solution. But if you want to disable a button you should not remove an attribute as you are doing but instead set the attribute

```
$("#title").prop("disabled", true)
```

Comment: Thanks I have done that but I want to inject this into the web page

Comment: Can you please describe in more detail what you want to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You will never get triggered the click event if the #title item is already disabled. You can use the parent item, or put the title into a div and bind the #myDiv.click event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myDiv').click(function () {
        $('#title').removeAttr("disable");
    });
});
```

Also, as Sjoerd2228888 points out, if you want to disable the element, you need to set the attribute disabled, not to remove it.